# How to display a double with no leading zero before the decimal in Java

Tags: java, methods, decimalformat

Class assignment: write a method to calculate the batting average of a baseball player. I need the output to be .345, but I keep getting 0.345. How do I format this output so no leading zeros before the decimal place are displayed? Thank you for any help offered.

This is the code in my BaseballPlayer class:

```
//BaseballPlayer parameters

String name;
int number;
int singles;
int doubles;
int triples;
int homeRuns;
int atBats;
int walks;
int sacrificeFlies;

//DecimalFormat

static DecimalFormat df  =   new DecimalFormat(".000");

//BaseballPlayer constructor method

public BaseballPlayer(String name, int number, int singles, int triples, int homeRuns, int atBats, int walks, 
        int sacrificeFlies)
{
    this.name            =   name;
    this.number          =   number;
    this.singles         =   singles;
    this.triples         =   triples;
    this.homeRuns        =   homeRuns;
    this.atBats          =   atBats;
    this.walks           =   walks;
    this.sacrificeFlies  =   sacrificeFlies;
}

public double getBattingAverage()
{
     return Double.parseDouble(df.format( (double) ( singles + doubles + triples + homeRuns ) / atBats) );
}
```

This is the code in my main class:

```
BaseballPlayer player01  =   new BaseballPlayer( "Mr. Business",13,12,13,4,84,63,7);

    System.out.println(player01.getBattingAverage());
```

My output:

run:

0.345

BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 0 seconds)

Comment: Your code snippet is fine, the problem is somewhere else in your code. Maybe post your statement that outputs the result?

Comment: Thank you for the help. I posted the code in my BaseballPlayer class and main class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are forgetting to format the actual output - you are formatting the value that goes into the `Double.parseDouble()` function, but not the actual result of the `getBattingAverage()` function, so the `System.out.println()` output is not what you expect. Your main method should look like:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    BaseballPlayer player01  =   new BaseballPlayer ( "Mr. Business",13,12,13,4,84,63,7);
    String str = df.format(player01.getBattingAverage());
    System.out.println(str);
}
```

---

If you want to format the actual getBattingAverage() output, you need to do the following:

```
public String getBattingAverage() {
    Double average = Double.parseDouble(df.format( (double) ( singles + doubles + triples + homeRuns ) / atBats) );
    return df.format(average);
}
```

And your main method then is like this:

```
Main player01  =   new Main( "Mr. Business",13,12, 13,4,84,63,7);
System.out.println(player01.getBattingAverage());
```

---

On a side unrelated note, I believe you are forgetting to set the doubles for your BaseballPlayer... So it will always be 0.

Answer (score 1):

Here's one way to do it.

```java
      double[] vals = { 0.233, .229, .292
      };
      for (double v : vals) {
         System.out.println(String.format("%.3f", v).substring(1));
      }
```

Comment: it's an elegant solution, as long as the numbers are positive.. if you have a negative value it doesn't work..

Comment: Batting averages are never negative.

Comment: of course they are never negative. but my version is generic, works for either + or - values...