# Here the .12 is converting to 0.12 but I want to avoid that

Tags: java, arrays, string, bigdecimal

The following code will convert the string array values into decimals and arrange them in descending order and again I have to print it as string, not decimals. The problem here is while converting the strings to decimals the ".1" value is changing to "0.1", but I need it to print that as ".1" only.

Code:

```
import java.math.BigDecimal;
import java.util.*;
class Solution{

    public static void main(String []args){
        //Input
        Scanner sc= new Scanner(System.in);
        int n=sc.nextInt();
        String []s=new String[n+2];
        for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
            s[i]=sc.next();
        }
        sc.close();
        BigDecimal[] d=new BigDecimal[n];
         for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
          d[i]=new BigDecimal(s[i]);
        }
        for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
        {
            for(int j=i+1;j<n;j++)
            {
                if(d[j].compareTo(d[i]) == 0)
                    continue;
                else if(d[j].compareTo(d[i]) > 0)
                {
                    BigDecimal t=d[i];
                    d[i]=d[j];
                    d[j]=t;
                    
                }
            }
        }
        
        for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
        {
            s[i]=d[i].toString();
        }
        
        //Output
        for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
        {
            System.out.println(s[i]);
        }
    }

}
```

Input:

```
9
-100
50
0
56.6
90
0.12
.12
02.34
000.000
```

Expected Output:

```
90
56.6
50
02.34
0.12
.12
0
000.000
-100
```

My Output:

```
90
56.6
50
2.34
0.12
0.12
0
0.000
-100
```

Comment: If you want them to appear as they do originally, why not just print the original strings?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to display a double with no leading zero before the decimal in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58150936/how-to-display-a-double-with-no-leading-zero-before-the-decimal-in-java)

Answer (score 2):

You have to create a class where you save both `String` and `double` values. When you compare items for sorting, you should use `double` value. When you print items, you should use `String` value.

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    scan.useLocale(Locale.ENGLISH);
    StringDoubleNumber[] numbers = readStringNumbers(scan);
    Arrays.sort(numbers);
    printDesc(numbers);
}

private static StringDoubleNumber[] readStringNumbers(Scanner scan) {
    System.out.print("Total numbers: ");
    int total = scan.nextInt();

    StringDoubleNumber[] numbers = new StringDoubleNumber[total];

    for (int i = 0; i < total; i++) {
        System.out.format("%d: ", i + 1);
        numbers[i] = new StringDoubleNumber(scan.next());
    }

    return numbers;
}

private static void printDesc(StringDoubleNumber[] numbers) {
    System.out.println("Numbers in descending order:");
    
    for (int i = numbers.length - 1; i >= 0; i--)
        System.out.println(numbers[i]);
}

private static final class StringDoubleNumber implements Comparable<StringDoubleNumber> {

    private final String str;
    private final double val;

    public StringDoubleNumber(String str) {
        this.str = str;
        val = Double.parseDouble(str);
    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(StringDoubleNumber obj) {
        return Double.compare(val, obj.val);
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return str;
    }

}
```

Comment: Very nice, you could use the `record` class here.

Answer (score 0):

I would store both the string and the number.  When printing, I would print the string.  When comparing, it would use the number.  To do that, I simply extends BigDecimal number and have an instance variable to store the string.  I also override the toString method to return the string.

```
class MyBigDecimal extends java.math.BigDecimal {
    private String str;
    public MyBigDecimal(String str){
        super(str);
        this.str = str.trim();
    }
    public String toString(){ return str; }
}

public class Main{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String input = "9 -100 50 0 56.6 90 0.12 .12 02.34 000.000";
        String [] items = input.split(" ");
        
        MyBigDecimal[] d = new MyBigDecimal[items.length];
        
        for(int i=0; i<items.length; i++)
            d[i] = new MyBigDecimal(items[i]);
        
        for(MyBigDecimal x: d)
            System.out.println(x);
        
    }
}
```

Output:

```
9
-100
50
0
56.6
90
0.12
.12
02.34
000.000
```

Comment: hello, i'm new learner to java i know about the super keyword but i'm little bit confused here, what is use of super(str).                                                                                                                     can you explain the code of MyBigDecimal class please..

Answer (score 0):

Well, since you have not specified any particular requirements or constraints you may as well do it like this.  You don't really need `BigDecimal`. This simply sorts on the double values and prints the strings.

- take in the values via your scanner and put them in an array (array is shown).
- Stream the array and sort in reversed order on the parsed Double using a Comparator.
- and assign the sorted array back to the original (or a different if you choose).
- and print the values

```
String[] v = { "56.6", "0.12", "-100", "02.34", "50",
        "000.000", "0", ".12", "90" };

v = Arrays.stream(v)
        .sorted(Comparator.comparingDouble(Double::parseDouble).reversed())
        .toArray(String[]::new);
    
for (String str: v) {
    System.out.println(str);
}
```

prints

```
90
56.6
50
02.34
0.12
.12
000.000
0
-100
```

If you want to use most of your original code, then simply maintain a separate array of the original string values. When you sort the doubles in your sorting algorithm, also swap the `original` string values using the same indices.  When time to print, print the string versions.

Answer (score 0):

This is one of the challenges in **HackerRank** and full solution to pass all the test-cases is as below. I checked the BigDecimal compare method, HashMap, SortedMap and etc. and this is the only correct solution i got.

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
int n = Integer.parseInt(scanner.nextLine());
if (n <= 200 && n >= 1) {
    String[] nums = new String[n];

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        nums[i] = scanner.nextLine();
    }
    nums = Arrays.stream(nums).sorted(Comparator.comparingDouble(Double::parseDouble).reversed()).toArray(String[]::new);

    for (String str: nums) {
        System.out.println(str);
    }
}
```